# How to get the number of persons joined per date in a month?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I inserted join date for every employee in a table like March 9, 2014, 10:50:29

After the completion of month ,I need to get the data like

march 9 => 20,
march 10 =>30, .....

I tried with group by statements along with count(*) , but i didn't got my required output. please help me...Thanks in advance..

Comment: `dont use date in string format`... use `timestamp` or `datetime`...

Comment: Post the table schema and whatever you tried so far.

Comment: I changed my column to date_time

Comment: Not quite understanding this: "After the completion of month ,I need to get the data like march 9 => 20, march 10 =>30, .....". Are you looking for qty of joins every 10 days of the month? Please clarify the daterange request.

Comment: After the completion of month i need a report like how many joined on each date in month

Comment: Gotcha.. date_time did the trick i use DATE(column_name) to group by DATE and count them using count()

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are using datetime field for storing the DateOfJoining.

Use this query, (Please replace table-name and fields as per yours)

```
SELECT DAY(joining_date) AS jdate, COUNT(*) AS jtotal
FROM your_table
WHERE MONTH(joining_date) = 3
GROUP BY jdate;
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DAY(joining_date) AS jdate, COUNT(*) AS jtotal
FROM your_table
WHERE MONTH(joining_date)=3 AND YEAR(joining_date)=2014
GROUP BY DAY(joining_date);
```

should work